# VB6 Listbox Copying

Tags: winforms, vb6, listbox-control

Using Visual Basic 6.0, I'm trying to populate one listbox with another listbox's items.

Can anyone please explain why the following sub fails to work properly,
getting a Type mismatch when passing two listboxes as parameters.

```
Public Sub copyListboxes(Byref lstFrom as Listbox, Byref lstTo as Listbox)
    Dim i as integer
    For i = 0 to lstFrom.Listcount -1
        lstTo.Additem lstFrom.List(i)
    Next i
End Sub

'Call copyListboxes(Listbox1,Listbox2) 'Type Mismatch ... ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No reason that shouldn't work. Are you sure you're passing ListBoxes in the call to the method?

Comment: @jac : sorry i didnt see your comment yet when i posted my answer ...

Comment: i was passing listbox instead of combobox, how could i not see that, Hrqls nailed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error by using Comboxes instead of Listboxes:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 command button: name=Command1
'  2 combobox controls: name=Listbox1 name=Listbox2
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Call copyListboxes(Listbox1, Listbox2) 'Type Mismatch!
End Sub

Public Sub copyListboxes(ByRef lstFrom As ListBox, ByRef lstTo As ListBox)
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To lstFrom.ListCount - 1
      lstTo.AddItem lstFrom.List(i)
  Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = 1 To 10
    Listbox1.AddItem CStr(intIndex)
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```

To solve this you can either use Listbox controls or change your sub to work with Combobox controls:

```
Public Sub copyListboxes(ByRef lstFrom As ComboBox, ByRef lstTo As ComboBox)
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To lstFrom.ListCount - 1
      lstTo.AddItem lstFrom.List(i)
  Next i
End Sub
```